# tab switch in js ,which is faster?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I always romoving 'current' class of all siblings then add 'current' class to my clicked one. I want to know will it be faster only removing 'current' class of which has 'current'.seems to be a simple question, but I really want to know.

[image]

Comment: Please insert copyable text instead of a picture. I'm not going to type the example when you could provide it for me to help you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, filtering the query to a smaller set of elements will perform faster, because there are less elements to check.

In modern browsers, jQuery will use native methods to query the DOM, so adding the selector has a negligible performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's much difference, since there's only one "current". It doesn't matters too much for querying one more element or one less.

Usually I'll first find out the outer element to narrow down

```
$('#selectionDiv').find() ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many elements you are re-classing, the impact of the optimization will of course vary.

I tested it, http://jsperf.com/reclassing-all-or-one, using 7 (seemed reasonable for for example navigation tabs) divs and I think the difference was significant (reclassing all 30% slower than only one), percentage wise. If one cares about actual time though it may not be, but I can't really see any reason not do be distinct.